# Can't decode a struct (invalid character '[' looking for beginning of object key string)

Tags: go, testing, struct, decode

I'm trying to send this mock data that I've prepared for testing one of my functions. It fails by saying 'invalid character '[' looking for beginning of object key string'. It is not able to decode the provided body into the Payload struct.

```
type Payload struct {
     Team      []map[string]interface{} `json:"teams"`
     Players   []map[string]interface{} `json:"players"`
     Time      map[string]interface{}   `json:"time"`
}

var Players Payload


body:= strings.NewReader(fmt.Sprintf("%v", Payload{
            Team: []map[string]interface{}{
                {
                    "location":"LA",
                    "number_of_members":"15992",
                    "name":"Los Angeles Lakers",
                    "rank":3,
                },
            },
            Players: []map[string]interface{}{
                {
                    "name":"Kuzma",
                    "championship":1,
                    "stats": map[string]interface{}{
                        "pts":   20,
                        "assists": 12,
                    },
                },
            },
            Time: map[string]interface{}{
                "endDate":          endDate,
                "isUpdateLineItem": isUpdateLineItem,
                "startDate":        startDate,
                "timezone":         timezone,
            },
        },
))


if err := json.NewDecoder(body).Decode(&Players); err != nil {
    errors.Write(rw, 400, "Unable to parse request body JSON or invalid data format.")
    return
}
```

Comment: fmt.Sprintf("%v",Payload{...}) will not generate valid json. Use json.Marshal instead.

Comment: @BurakSerdar I need the data as string, that's why i'm converting it to a string with sprintf. json.Marshall returns []byte and throws an error anyways Edit:it doesn't throw an error but it returns a byte array [1 12 21313 23] something like this

Comment: If you convert it with sprintf, json decoder will give the error you said because it is not valid json. To generate valid json, use json.Marshal, and convert the []byte output to string.

Comment: oh i get it now... Thanks @BurakSerdar

Comment: As Burak Says: https://play.golang.org/p/Q-UFEK8sHRY